# Moving a rover and receiving current coordinates

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, coordinate-system

I made a little text-based game where you move a rover and it gives you the current coordinates. You can essentially move around a 1000x1000 grid, and get output into `stdout` on what your coordinates are. I'm simply wondering if I could improve anything.

```
# Rover moving program
from random import randint 

# Starting position for rover
r_pos = {'x': randint(1, 1000), 'y': randint(1, 1000)}

def move_rover(x_pos, y_pos):
    if x_pos <= 1000 and y_pos <= 1000:
        r_pos['x'] = x_pos
        r_pos['y'] = y_pos
        print('x{} y{}'.format(
            r_pos['x'], r_pos['y']))
    elif x_pos > 1000 and y_pos > 1000:
        print('Invalid position: x{} y{}'.format(
            x_pos, y_pos))
```

You run it like this.

```
>>> import rover
>>> rover.move_rover(234, 789)
x234 y789
```

Comment: "I made a little text-based game where you move a rover and it gives you the current coordinates." I doubt that; this is a standard test question called 'the Mars rover'. It is quite well-known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Validation

Your validation is weird, and probably not what you intended.

- `move_rover(-1, -1)` appears to succeed, even though it's not within your 1000 × 1000 grid.
- `move_rover(-1, 1001)` is a no-op.  `move_rover(1001, 500)` is a no-op.

`move_rover(2000, 2000)` prints a message.  However, it would be more idiomatic to [raise some kind of `ValueError`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/256222/1157100).  Printing the error message directly limits the reusability of your code.

### Output

Similarly, I advise against having your `move_rover()` function also print the new coordinates.  Each function should do one thing only.  Printing should be a separate operation.

There is repetition in the code to format the position in the success and error cases.  The formatting code should be factored out to a common routine.

### Representation

Using a dictionary with keys named `'x'` and `'y'` seems cumbersome.  You could use a tuple, a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)` or class.  A class probably make sense, since your rover should act as an object that responds to messages.

### Suggested implementation

```
from random import randint

MIN_COORD, MAX_COORD = 1, 1000

class Rover(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Places the rover randomly in the coordinate range with a uniform
        distribution"""
        self.x = randint(MIN_COORD, MAX_COORD)
        self.y = randint(MIN_COORD, MAX_COORD)

    def move(self, x, y):
        if MIN_COORD <= x <= MAX_COORD and MIN_COORD <= y <= MAX_COORD:
            self.x, self.y = x, y
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid position: %s' % (self))

    def __str__(self):
        """Reports the position of the rover"""
        return 'x{} y{}'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

You run it like this:

```
>>> from rover import Rover
>>> rover = Rover()
>>> print(rover)
x944 y556
>>> rover.move(234, 789)
>>> print(rover)
x234 y789
```

Comment: Note that this also removes the "global" variable `r_pos`. It seems odd to mix `%` (`move`) and `str.format` (`__str__`), though!