# Text-based rover game

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, game

I've made a small "rover game" similar to [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57550/moving-a-rover-and-receiving-current-coordinates), except made in C#, using OOP, and prettier menus. Here's how it works:

There is one `Rover` class which is instantiated into an array containing all rovers. This class contains certain actions that a rover might need like, `MoveRover`, or `RoverDead`. There is also a `RoverManager` class where actions such as updating rovers are executed by looping through the array where the rover data is stored. This is also where rover addition and deletion is managed as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rovers
{
    /* A class for creating a rover */
    class Rover
    {
        public long x;
        public long y;
        public string name;
        public int lifeTime;

        public Rover(long x, long y, string name, int lifeTime)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.name = name;
            this.lifeTime = lifeTime;
        }

        /* Update the rover lifetime */
        public void UpdateRoverLifeTime(int xChange, int yChange)
        {
            this.lifeTime -= Math.Abs(xChange - yChange);
        }

        /* Move the rover a desired amount */
        public void MoveRover(int xChange, int yChange)
        {
            if (xChange <= 5 && yChange <= 5 && xChange >= -5 && yChange >= -5)
            {
                this.x += xChange;
                this.y += yChange;
                UpdateRoverLifeTime(xChange, yChange);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPOSITION CHANGE MUST BE <= 5 or >= -5.");
            }
        }

        /* Get input for position changes of the rover */
        public void GetRoverPositionChange()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n-- Rover Position Changer Menu. --");

            Console.Write("xChange: ");
            int xChange = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("yChange: ");
            int yChange = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            MoveRover(xChange, yChange);
        }

        /* Output rover statistics */
        public void OutputRoverStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n-- Rover Stats Menu. --");
            Console.WriteLine("Rover: {0}", this.name);
            Console.WriteLine("x: {0}, y: {1}", this.x, this.y);
            Console.WriteLine("Life: {0}", this.lifeTime);
        }

        /* Is the rover dead? :( https://xkcd.com/695/ */
        public bool RoverDead()
        {
            return this.lifeTime > 0;
        }

        /* Main rover update "loop" */
        public void UpdateRover()
        {
            GetRoverPositionChange();
            OutputRoverStats();
        }
    }


    /* A class containing certain methods for rover managment */
    class RoverManager
    {
        public List<Rover> roverList = new List<Rover>();

        /* Add a rover */
        public void AddRover()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n-- Add Rover Menu. --");

            Console.Write("startX: ");
            long startX = (long)Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("startY: ");
            long startY = (long)Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("startingLifeTime: ");
            int startingLifeTime = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            this.roverList.Add(new Rover(startX, startY, name, startingLifeTime));
        }

        /* Destroy a rover if it's dead */
        public void DestroyRovers()
        {
            for (int n = roverList.Count-1; n >= 0; n--)
            {
                Rover rover = roverList[n];

                if (rover.RoverDead())
                {
                    roverList.Remove(rover);
                }
            }
        }

        /* Update each rover */
        public void UpdateRovers()
        {
            for (int n = roverList.Count-1; n >= 0; n--)
            {
                Rover rover = roverList[n];
                rover.UpdateRover();
            }
        }

        /* Main rover manager loop */
        public void MainManagerLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                AddRover();
                UpdateRovers();
                DestroyRovers();
            }
        }
    }


    public class MainProgram
    {
        private static RoverManager roverManager = new RoverManager();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            roverManager.MainManagerLoop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> public List<Rover> roverList = new List<Rover>();
> ```

This field can (and should) be made private.  We don't want strangers messing around with our rovers!

While we're at it, let's change the name from `roverList` to `rovers` -- we don't need the name to reflect the fact that it's a *list* of rovers.

Finally, we can make the field [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

---

> ```
> public void DestroyRovers()
> {
>     for (int n = roverList.Count-1; n >= 0; n--)
>     {
>         Rover rover = roverList[n];
>
>         if (rover.RoverDead())
>         {
>             roverList.Remove(rover);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Here we're removing all the dead rovers from the list. There's a method [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) that can do this for us.

```
public void DestroyRovers()
{
    this.rovers.RemoveAll(rover => rover.RoverDead());
}
```

`rover.RoverDead()` looks strange to me; I think `IsDead` would be a better name. `IsDead` is a good candidate for a property since we're just returning the result of a quick comparison, so let's change this

> ```
> public bool RoverDead()
> {
>     return this.lifeTime > 0;
> }
> ```

to this

```
public bool IsDead
{
    get { return this.lifeTime > 0; }
}
```

Now our method looks better:

```
public void DestroyRovers()
{
    this.rovers.RemoveAll(rover => rover.IsDead);
}
```

---

> ```
> public void UpdateRovers()
> {
>     for (int n = roverList.Count-1; n >= 0; n--)
>     {
>         Rover rover = roverList[n];
>         rover.UpdateRover();
>     }
> }
> ```

We can use `Enumerable.Reverse` to do the reversing for us. It's not much of a change, but I think it makes it a little easier for the reader to see exactly what is happening:

```
public void UpdateRovers()
{
    foreach (var rover in Enumerable.Reverse(this.rovers))
    {
        rover.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reverse iteration in `UpdateRovers` looks like a copy-paste from `DestroyRovers`. The reverse in `DestroyRovers` is because the collection is being modified while it's being iterated. If it actually requires reversed iteration it should, in my opinion, be delegated to the storage.

Comment: I like that you mention the LINQ ideas. I just don't think they are beginner material. Yes it is easier to read, yes it is easier to write, yes it is more powerful. But does the OP understand extension methods, or Func? We don't know the answer to that, but we can assume not since it was not used. Just my two cents. Good coverage though!

Comment: I don't like the change roverList to rovers idea. Just adding the 's' doesn't make it as obvious that it is a collection of rovers as roverList does. If you want to change roverList to roverCollection or similar then fine, but using simply 'rovers' makes the code less readable. You are also making the assumption that using the word 'List' means that a 'List' class is actually used, when that isn't necessarily true. My definition of readable is that you don't have to 'pause' and think about what a particular name means while reading the code.

Comment: @Dunk I prefer to use a plural term rather than describe the enumeration type. I'm not certain why you feel that using a plural term to describe a typed List/Collection/Enumerable would require a 'pause' to think about whether it would contain just one or potentially many.

Comment: @RobertSnyder I don't see a need to limit CodeReview responses to 'beginner material'. The OP does indicate that they are new to the language and asks to have advanced topics explained, not avoided.

Comment: @psaxton-The reason it makes me pause is because there are many kinds of collections of things and many times it matters what type of collection. e.g. List versus Queue matters.  There are even cases where appending the 's' is natural to describe the variable but doesn't end up being a list or collection of objects. Thus, each time I see a 's' word then I have to investigate the intent. Too me, appending List, Queue or Collection conveys the missing semantic information that simply using 's' doesn't, but it still doesn't specify the implementation.

Comment: @RobertSnyder: New developers tend to always learn the technology that is current when they learn to code. I come from the pre-LINQ era, but students today learn about collection transformation methods pretty much immediately after being shown collections. It's counterproductive to force new developers to linger as much in the absolute basics as their predecessors once did. When you went to school, you likely weren't taught to farm or hunt. You were taught things that were appropriate for your time period.

Comment: @RobertSnyder: I'm aware that my comment is 4 years younger than yours; but it sort of proves the point. Do you now (in 2019) still consider LINQ too advanced for a beginner?

Answer (score 13):

The answer of **mjolka** is already showing several good points. Here are some additional remarks:

### Fields => Properties

You're not using the fields outside the class, so why make them public? You have two options, make the fields private or create a property with a private setter. I'd prefer the second choice:

```
public long X { get; private set; }
public long Y { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; private set; }
public int LifeTime { get; private set; }
```

Now you can still use them the same way like before, and only *set* the values from within the class. *Reading* the values is also possible from outside the class.

### Input validation:

One of the first things that struck me is that you never validate user input. Your program will throw a `System.FormatException` when entering non-numeric input. You'll have to provide some way to catch this.

Change following line:

```
int xChange = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

to:

```
int xChange;
var xValid = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out xChange);
```

This also goes for the y coordinate. Now you can nicely validate against these boolean fields and ask for coordinates again if the input is not valid:

```
if (xValid && yValid)
{
    MoveRover(xChange, yChange);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unknown rover input, please try again:");
    GetRoverPositionChange();
}
```

You must also apply this kind of validation elsewhere in your code where you ask for input.

### Logical errors:

The variable name `lifeTime` confused me. You checked for:

```
public bool RoverDead()
{
    return this.lifeTime > 0;
}
```

According to the above method, the rover is dead from the moment the `lifeTime` variable is greater than 0. But when you're moving the rover, you're subtracting the change from the lifetime, making him more and more alive. But you can't make him more alive since he will be dead from the beginning when you give the rover a lifetime of any positive number.

This doesn't make sense to me. Rename the `lifeTime` variable to `RemainingLifeTime` and use the property suggested by mjolka:

```
public bool IsAlive
{
    get { return RemainingLifeTime > 0; }
}
```

Now when the remaining lifetime is greater than 0, your rover can happily move and will die when you keep subtracting the changes from its *remaining* lifetime. This gets me to another error in the logic. This is the formula you use to calculate the number to subtract from the lifetime:

```
public void UpdateRoverLifeTime(int xChange, int yChange)
{
    RemainingLifeTime -= Math.Abs(xChange - yChange);
}
```

If this can be applied in real life, the Mars Rover could keep going indefinitely, as long as the change of X is equal to the change of Y. Example:

- Start X: 0
- Start Y: 0
- Name: test
- Starting LifeTime: 2

Now give 5 as input for `xChange` and `yChange` and voila... infinite power for the fella!

Rethink a better way to calculate this, you could for example use a Pythagorean function:

> a² = b² + c²

Your formula would become:

```
var deltaChange = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(xChange * xChange + yChange * yChange));
```

You will have to adjust the maximum and minimum allowed change though, as for now you'll only allow very small moves.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quick question, why are you using `var` to declare `deltaChange` when you could just use `int`?

Comment: @Ethan Bierlein because the type is obvious from the right hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 7):

*(This is in addition to mjolka's review.)*

---

What are these, [fields of properties](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx)? If they're fields they should be private; if they're properties they should have a getter/setter.

```
public long x;
public long y;
public string name;
public int lifeTime;
```

---

Putting a lot of trust in your user here:

```
Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

What happens if he/she doesn't enter an `int`?

---

Same issue as before: is this a field or a property?

```
public List<Rover> roverList = new List<Rover>();
```

---

Why parse the input to an `int` (also: again you're putting a lot of trust in your user) and then cast it to a `long`?

```
long startX = (long)Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I know, your `Rover` expects a `long`. But why is that necessary?

Comment: Hehe... A field of properties. ++ I like a good pun.

Comment: @RubberDuck D'oh, that's a typo. My finger must have slipped from the r to the f key below. Well, now I'm leaving it in. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you come from a java world based on your comments over your methods, and the use of your fields instead of properties. Neither of these things are bad, just not what we are used to seeing in the C# world. If you are using Visual Studio you can type a triple forwards slash and it will make a xml style comment that intellisense can and will use. example use would be

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a rover
    /// </summary>
    public void AddRover()

    /// <summary>
    /// Is the rover dead?
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>returns true if the rover is dead</returns>
    /// <remarks>https://xkcd.com/695/</remarks>
    public bool RoverDead()

    /// <summary>
    /// Move the rover a desired amount
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xChange">the amount to move the rover on the x coordinate</param>
    /// <param name="yChange">the amount to move the rover on the y coordinate</param>
    public void MoveRover(int xChange, int yChange)
```

Another helpful thing to learn about is the power of some of the testing frameworks at your disposal. As it sits right now NUnit is probably the most popular. MSTest isn't horrible. I've never used xUnit so I can't speak for it. whichever you choose is up to you. In terms of speed and easiest to setup MSTest will be the way to go. I also recommend using Fluent assertions (search for it using Nuget) with it, but that is more of a personal preference then anything else.

Now I'm not going to get into the debate of what style of testing to use be it test-after (write a test after you've written your production code) TDD, BDD or a combination there of. I will say though that if you write your test first and try to make your tests pass your code will be more testable. Just like writing production code has a certain art to it, so does writing good tests. It all takes practice.

With that said I will focus now on a comment made in a post up above by Abbas

> If this can be applied in real life, the Mars Rover could keep going indefinitely, as long as the change of X is equal to the change of Y. Example:
>
> ```
> Start X: 0
> Start Y: 0
> Name: test
> Starting LifeTime: 2
> ```
>
> Now give 5 as input for xChange and yChange and voila... infinite power for the fella!

Instead of typing in those values that he speaks of a the console window you can write a test to assume certain things.

```
[TestClass]
public class RoverTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AfterMovingRoverLifeDecreases()
    {
        var rover = new Rover(0, 0, "test", 6);
        rover.MoveRover(2, 4);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, rover.lifeTime, "rover moved 6, so life should be 0");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AbbasFoundThisBug()
    {
        var rover = new Rover(0, 0, "test", 2);
        rover.MoveRover(5, 5);
        Assert.AreEqual(-8, rover.lifeTime, "rover moved 10, so life should be -8");
    }
}
```

those tests fails currently (I did that on purpose). It took 17ms to run on my PC and said the following.

```
Test Name:  AfterMovingRoverLifeDecreases
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.017907
Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<4>. rover moved 6, so life should be 0

Test Name:  AbbasFoundThisBug
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0006728
Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<-8>. Actual:<2>. rover moved 10, so life should be -8
```

(I guessed at the assertions for how much life should be remaining and how to calculate life)

Comment: Nice elaboration on the unit testing. May I only point out that my name is Abbas and not Abbus. :D

Comment: @Abbas nice :) thank you for finding that. It is corrected